# Two y axes for a single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a plot with two Y axes (left and right) for the same data, that is, one is a scaled version of the other. I would like also to preserve the tick positions and grid positions, so the grid will match the ticks at both sides.

I'm trying to do this by plotting twice the same data, one as-is and the other scaled, but they are not coincident.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(17, 27, 0.1)
y1 = 0.05 * x + 100

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
ax2.plot(x, y1/max(y1), 'g-')

ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y data', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y data normalized', color='b')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can achieve this without getting ugly-looking numbers on your normalized axis. But if that doesn't bother you, try adding this to your code:

```
ax2.set_ylim([ax1.get_ylim()[0]/max(y1),ax1.get_ylim()[1]/max(y1)])
ax2.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks()/max(y1))
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it scales your axis limits and tick positions similarly to what you do with the data itself so the grid matches both axes.

Comment: Thank you. This can do the trick. I don't expect both axes to have well-rounded numbers, yes, but right axis will be as percentage so I will format them accordingly.

Comment: Turning on the grid-option might help in give the impression that it is the same ticks.

Comment: I've tried with another data set and it is not working. Simply using 'y1=0.05*x+100' will plot two different scales and two plots are shown.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the case when not all of the yticks of `ax1` are within the axis limits. Try to add one more line:

`ax1.set_ylim([min(ax1.get_yticks()),max(ax1.get_yticks())])`